# FileWriter y FileOutputStream con System.in.read

Tags: java, archivo

cuando leo una matriz con `System.in.read` usando un buffer declarado como

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[81];
```

Y luego escribo en un fichero con `FileOutputStream` escribe las tildes como "qué". El comportamiento para este caso, con `FileWriter` es el mismo. Entonces cuál es la diferencia, por que si en el primero usa bytes para escribir en el fichero, pero para una tilde, hasta donde yo sé, tiene que utilizar dos bytes para representarlo con lo que sería lo mismo para `FileWriter`.

Entonces ¿Cuál es la diferencia?, porque con `System.in.read(buffer, 0, 81)` también almacena tildes.

Gracias de antemano.

Un cordial saludo.

Comment: El unico problema que veo es que no conoces bien las clases para lectura y escritura de Java. `System.in` es un `InputStream` y como tal usa binario, `FileWriter` es un writer y por lo tanto usa cadenas. Uno lee y otro escribe ¿qué más diferencia es la que no entiendes?

Comment: La duda es, FileOutputStream escribe cada carácter como un byte? y FileWriter escribe cada carácter como dos bytes? Es que en el código usando un array de bytes leídos con System.in.read el resultado es el mismo

Comment: fos escribe cada byte como byte, no entiende de carcateres, fw escribe cada caracter como caracter y por lo tanto no entiende de bytes, esa es la diferencia, (a pesar de que se pueda hacer compisición). Tu arreglo funciona como un buffer, es decir un espacio de memoria para mejorar el desempeño de la escritura, y no tiene nada que ver con el tamaño de tus archivos o tus entradas. Los writer son una implementación posterior a los streams (y a veces se consideran con nivel mayor de abstracción) por lo que internamente pueden tener algunos streams con o sin buffer.